# C# -- Using multiple DataTables of the same name and namespace in a DataSet

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2008

suppose I have an MS SQL Server database table named "GROUPS" such as the following:

```
GROUP_ID    GROUP_NAME    DESCRIPTION
    1        Grp1            Null
    2        Grp2            Null
    3        Grp3            Test
```

GROUP_ID is an auto increment primary field, GROUP_NAME is a unique non-null varchar field, and Description is a null-allowed (optional) varchar field.

I am trying to produce some XML output as a web service, to be consumed by some other process, of the table information.
The XML must be output in a specific manner.

The end goal would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GROUPS>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION/>
    </GROUP>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp2</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION/>
    </GROUP>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Test</DESCRIPTION>
    </GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

This procedure almost gets the desired goal:

```
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS";
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"; // Set the page to output XML
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn); // SQL Adapter, conn is an already open SQL connection
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("GROUPS"); // Root Node of XML doc will be "GROUPS"
        da.Fill(ds, "GROUP"); // Each record node is a "GROUP"
        XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(Response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.None }; // XML writer
        xml.WriteStartDocument(); // XML header
        ds.WriteXml(xml); // Write XML output
```

The issue with this procedure is that it does not provide the desired empty nodes such as  for null values in the table.  It would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GROUPS>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
    </GROUP>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp2</GROUP_NAME>
    </GROUP>
    <GROUP>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Test</DESCRIPTION>
    </GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

After doing some research, an attempt to create the desired output was performed with the following procedure:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS";
        SqlDataReader row = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("GROUPS");

        while (row.Read())
        {

            DataTable table1 = new DataTable("GROUP" + row["GROUP_ID"]); // This line is the issue
            object[] columns = new object[row.FieldCount];


            for (int i = 0; i < row.FieldCount; i++)
            {

                string name = row.GetName(i);

                    table1.Columns.Add(name);
                    columns[i] = DBstr(row[i]);

            }

            table1.Rows.Add(columns);
            ds.Tables.Add(table1);

        }

        row.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/xml"; // Set the page to output XML
        XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(Response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.None }; // XML writer
        xml.WriteStartDocument(); // XML header
        ds.WriteXml(xml, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema); // Write XML output


    public static string DBstr(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return String.Empty; // Default value for null DB value
        }

        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return ((DateTime)obj).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            return obj.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that I had to give either a unique name for each DataTable, or a unique namespace.  Prior to writing out xml from the DataSet.
So it would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GROUPS>
    <GROUP1>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION/>
    </GROUP1>
    <GROUP2>
        <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp2</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION/>
    </GROUP2>
    <GROUP3>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
        <GROUP_NAME>Grp1</GROUP_NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Test</DESCRIPTION>
    </GROUP3>
</GROUPS>
```

Or, each GROUP row would have an xmlns tag thrown in.

Either way, undesirable.  So what is the simplest way to get the desired goal using C# here?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `new XmlTextWriter()`. You should use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the query

> string sql = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS";

to below

```
string sql = "SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME, IsNull(DESCRIPTION, '') as DESCRIPTION  FROM GROUPS";
```

Comment: Handling this on the query side is definitely a clever, and easy solution to this specific problem, and one I had not considered.  For this specific problem this solution works.

Comment: I am still however, curious, if I had to create a DataSet from scratch in C#, as in not using a data adapter.  How would I go about constructing it in C# to produce the desired XML using the DataSet's writeXML method?

Answer (score 0):

Without a custom serializer I don't think you can achieve what you want.  DataTable names are unique by design, and the serialization of a DataSet respects that uniqueness for the somewhat obvious reason that they have to be deserializable, meaning the names have to be unique after serialization.

Comment: I understand this.  At this point I can create a desired output by manipulating the query.  How is it that a SqlDataAdapter can create a DataSet with a single table that produces the desired output with WriteXML?  If I were to forgo the SqlDataAdapter and instead manually iterate over each row of the query result I cannot seem to create a similar DataSet that the adapter creates.

Comment: Nevermind I solved my own issue.  Apparently I don't need to add a DataTable for each "record/row" in the XML.  Only one table is needed, they all take on the name of the single table.